# I'm trying to build a Data lake using GCS, Orchestrator and Dataflow. I've Push and Pull apis from Servicenow. How should I build it?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to build a Data lake using GCS, Orchestrator and Dataflow. I've Push and Pull apis from Servicenow. How should I build it? I may use Bigquery or GCS for Datalake. Can anyone help me with a detailed workflow?

I tried this model, I'm looking for architecture diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

**Storage**: You can use Cloud Storage as the data lake, Cloud Storage is well suited to serve as the central storage repository for many reasons as Performance and durability
Strong consistency, Cost efficiency, Flexible processing, Central repository and Security

**Data ingestion:** You can use Pub/Sub and Dataflow.

You can ingest and store real-time data directly into Cloud Storage, scaling both in and out in response to data volume.

**Processing and analytics** : After you have ingested and stored data, the next step is to make it available for analysis.

For instance, if you store incoming data in Avro format in Cloud Storage, you can do the following:

- Use Hive on Dataproc to issue SQL queries against the data.
- Issue queries directly against the data from BigQuery.
- Load the data into BigQuery and then query it.

**Data mining and exploration:**

Because a large portion of the data stored in the lake is not ready for immediate consumption, you must first mine this data for latent value.

For powerful SQL-based analysis, you can transform raw data with Dataprep by Trifacta and load it into BigQuery.

**Design and deploy workflows:**

Making a data subset more widely available means creating focused data marts. You can keep these data marts up to date by using orchestrated data pipelines that take raw data and transform it into a format that downstream processes and users can consume.

**- You can do Transformation of raw data and load into BigQuery**

You use an extract, transform, and load (ETL) process to ingest data into a BigQuery data warehouse. You can then query the data by using SQL. Dataprep, a visual tool for cleansing and preparing data, is well suited for simple ETL jobs, while Dataflow with Apache Beam provides additional flexibility for more involved ETL jobs.

For more information you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/build-a-data-lake-on-gcp).